# How best to implement ASP.Net routing to handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

The web application is .Net 4.0 and is part Web Form's, part MVC.  Rather than accessing the styles directly, the site uses an handler.  Here is the real link:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/CssManager.ashx?s=StyleSheetName")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Styles/CssManager.ashx?s=StyleSheetName" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Ideally I would like to use this URL:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Styles/StyleSheetName.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="~/Styles/StyleSheetName.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

The main reason is so the browser will catch the page.  Can this be done by adding a route to the RouteCollection or must one go to IIS?  I am trying to avoid the later, fore this is an intranet application we sell to our customers, who often know little about this stuff, so I am trying to keep it as simple as possible for them.

---

Q1: am I replacing this with an action?

A1: I had not thought of that, is it an option? (I updated the examples to be both web forms and mvc.

Comment: Can you replace the ASHX with an MVC action?

Answer (score 1):

You could create custom IRouteHandler:

```
public class CssManagerHttpHandlerRouteHandler : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        CssManager handler = new CssManager();
        HttpContext.Current.Items["s"] = requestContext.RouteData.Values["s"];

        return handler;
    }
}
```

and then map it in your global.asax.cs file:

```
routes.Add(new Route("Styles/StyleSheetName.css", 
            new RouteValueDictionary { { "s", "StyleSheetName" } },
            new CssManagerHttpHandlerRouteHandler()));
```

However, you cannot change HttpContext.Request.QueryString or any other request-params collections. So the most "clear" way to pass arguements from RequestContext to HttpContext is use HttpContext.Current.Items collection. This might require some changes in your CssManager handler class.

You may also want to see [this article](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Mar/28/Custom-ASPNET-Routing-to-an-HttpHandler).